# DevExtreme using Angular Aproach - onValueChanged not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devextreme

My objective is to alert a message when i click in a number in my calendar widget of the devExtreme Framework.

Its not working... could some one help me please ?

HTML - >

```
<div id="calendar-container" dx-calendar="{
    onValueChanged: valueChangedHandler                        
}">
</div>
```

JS - >

```
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

$scope.onValueChanged = function () {
    alert('aaa');
};

});
```

The callendar biding options are working fine. but not the click handler.

Thanks and happy new year.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I've just create the sample here - http://plnkr.co/edit/ack6MMAR7hkhJgQHeAjl?p=preview And it works fine.

Comment: Sergey , it works, thanks for the help, thanks for the plunker !!

Answer (score 3):

I have re-posted Sergey's comment as a new Answer. You can accept it to close/complete this thread/issue:

Here is an online example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ack6MMAR7hkhJgQHeAjl?p=preview

Here is some code from the example:

Html markup:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div dx-calendar="{ onValueChanged: onValueChanged }"></div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["dx"]);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.value = new Date(2015, 11, 6);
    $scope.onValueChanged = function(){
       alert('hello');
    };
});
```